# How to ensure domain integrity when using an ORM

Tags: mysql, database-design, orm, doctrine-orm

In addition to declaring a columns type, how should domain integrity be enforced?

`ENUM()` is an option, however, it has drawbacks from a SQL perspective as well as a [Doctrine](https://www.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/2.6/cookbook/mysql-enums.html) perspective.

As an alternative, when designing a database before using an ORM, I would instead use natural keys and foreign constraints.  While my `time_unit` table has a name and seconds column, the only real point of it is to restrict values in other tables to that of `time_unit.unit`.

```
MariaDB [tracker]> select * from time_unit;
+------+-----------+----------+
| unit | name      | seconds  |
+------+-----------+----------+
| d    | Days      |    86400 |
| h    | Hours     |     3600 |
| i    | Minutes   |       60 |
| m    | Month     |  2592000 |
| q    | Quarter   | 10368000 |
| s    | Seconds   |        1 |
| w    | Week      |   604800 |
| y    | Year      | 31536000 |
+------+-----------+----------+
8 rows in set (0.01 sec)

MariaDB [tracker]> select * from sign;
+------+
| sign |
+------+
|   -1 |
|    1 |
+------+
2 rows in set (0.00 sec)

CREATE TABLE `agenda` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `time_value` smallint(6) DEFAULT NULL,
  `time_unit` varchar(1) COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  `sign` smallint(6) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  KEY `fk_agenda_time_unit1_idx` (`time_unit`),
  KEY `fk_agenda_sign1_idx` (`sign`),
  CONSTRAINT `FK_5A9C89CF7106057E` FOREIGN KEY (`time_unit`) REFERENCES `time_unit` (`unit`),
  CONSTRAINT `FK_22ACC67D9F7E91FE` FOREIGN KEY (`sign`) REFERENCES `sign` (`sign`),
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4 COLLATE=utf8mb4_unicode_ci
```

But this has issues when using an ORM.  First of all, an object is created for each which seems excessive and makes serialization a pain.  Secondly, I've [read](https://www.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/2.6/tutorials/getting-started.htm) that when using an ORM, one shouldn't be working with foreign keys but the associated objects.

> At the database level, relationships between entities are represented
>   by foreign keys. But with Doctrine, you'll never have to (and never
>   should) work with the foreign keys directly. You should only work with
>   objects that represent foreign keys through their own identities.

To enforce domain integrity, should ENUM(), foreign constraints to a natural key, or some other approach be used?

Comment: What do you mean by "domain integrity"?  Probably the rules for such are too complex to be implemented in the meager capabilities of SQL, even using Triggers, FKs, datatypes, CONSTRAINTs, etc.  Do it in your client code.

Comment: @RickJames  I am referring to ensuring a given column value must be in a specified  group of possible values.  FK normally works great, but then Doctrine will try to create an object for it which is not desired.

Comment: `<snide-remark>` Sometimes 3rd-party software gets in the way more than it helps. `</snide-remark>`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is mostly a question of style. When you're building a schema, referential integrity is a way of guaranteeing quality. There are other ways of doing that - for instance, unit tests which guarantee that the system will not accept "sign" values other than 1 and -1.

So, where you have a table that you use just to limit the valid entries, if there are no additional attributes, I'd suggest doing the simplest possible thing and put that logic in your application layer, with unit tests to verify the behaviour you want. Just store the data in the database as an integer with no foreign keys.

If you really want to have the database validate entries, you could use an enum, or tell the ORM that the column is just an integer, but still create the foreign key. Whether this is a good idea is again down to style. I very much prefer "DRY" - don't repeat yourself. If you have logic to limit the valid options for an attribute in your application layer, focus on making that better, don't repeat that logic in the database schema. It's not that cut and dried though - if you think people will access the database outside your application, there's a legitimate case for having a foreign key or enum.

I think your `time_unit` is more than a set of lookup values - I'm guessing the "seconds" column is used for converting between units. There are a couple of options here, but again I'd want to rely on unit tests to verify my conversion logic, and you might consider storing these as constants in your application code if that's where the conversion logic happens. You can then store the unit as a char column in the agenda table.

This makes your persistence logic easier and faster, but places the responsibility for verifying behaviour into your unit tests, rather than your schema.

I think the quote about never using foreign keys directly is intended to suggest that the "normal" behaviour using your ORM would be to access time_unit by asking for the agenda object (`print agendaItem.time_unit.name`), rather than explicitly asking for the foreign key and retrieving the related object (`timeUnitID = agendaItem.timeUnitID; print time_unit.findByID(timeUnitID`). I don't think it's blanket advice against foreign keys.

Comment: Thanks Neville,  For the "sign" table, why wouldn't one include the foreign key constraint so that the DB just enforces the allowed values, but have the ORM ignore the sign table so it does not  create a `Sign` object?

Comment: I've updated the answer to reflect that - I prefer "don't repeat yourself", but it's a question of style...

Answer (score 0):

> ENUM() is an option, however, it has drawbacks from a SQL perspective
>   as well as a Doctrine perspective.
>
> To enforce domain integrity, should ENUM(), foreign constraints to a
>   natural key, or some other approach be used?

You can replace MySQL's / MariaDB's datatype

```
ENUM('1', '2', '3');
```

With more a rational approach.

```
    CREATE TABLE enum_data (
       position TINYINT
     , value CHAR(1)
    );

INSERT INTO enum_data (position, value) VALUES(1, '1');
INSERT INTO enum_data (position, value) VALUES(2, '2');
INSERT INTO enum_data (position, value) VALUES(3, '3');
```

And use it in your table

```
CREATE TABLE your_table (
   id INT ....
 , enum_data_id TINYINT
 ...
 ...
)
```

Offcource you also can/should also use `FOREIGN KEY` to ensure data integrity with the rational approach. 
Also using a extra table has the advantage over the `ENUM`. 
When you want to add, edit, remove from the `ENUM` datatype you will have to need to use `ALTER TABLE` which is offcource not required when using a other table.

Comment: Thanks Raymond.  Wouldn't this result in an `EnumData` object being created? 
 And a little off topic but would you recommend only using surrogate keys when using an ORM?

Comment: @user1032531 i didnt work with doctrine for a long time now.. Also i can’t make a suggestion if you should or should not use surrogate keys that has way to much thoery behide it.. also i dont know your datamodel and if you have natural keys that dont change to use

Comment: Thanks again.  Understood.  Just curious, but are you using another ORM?  I've always just homespun my SQL and executed using PHP, and this whole Doctrine thing has taken more time than I expected.

Comment: *" Just curious, but are you using another ORM?"* i've build and using mine own abstraction  database layer @user1032531 which supports Object-relational mapping, Active Record, direct quering and query building with method chaining across database vendors.. it also supports optimizing queries in a transaction for example multiple updates queries will be rewritten as one update query with a case statement in it.